# Installing jdk 1.7.0 java -version not working

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, java, jdk

I have installed java jdk, following the steps as described [here](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/04/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-12-04-precise-pangolin/) but the problem is when i do `which jav` it gives me the output

> /usr/bin/java

but when i do `java -version` it says

> bash: /usr/bin/java: No such file or directory

im using ubuntu 12.04 LTS...

Comment: Please paste the output of `ls -l /usr/bin/java`. And if it is a link, also paste the output of `ls -l` of its destination.

Comment: @binfalse `lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22 Oct 13 18:29 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java
`

Comment: Does `/etc/alternatives/java` exist?

Comment: @KevinPanko nope :(

Comment: That explains the error you got.  Now the next question is why not?

Comment: @KevinPanko plz guide me how can i make it work...

Comment: Did you follow all the directions?  Especially the part about `sudo update-alternatives`

Comment: yup, all three commands i have executed